# How create .app for mac osx from tcl script applicaton

Tags: macos, tcl

I have anyProject.tcl script application. It working properly in MAC OSX from terminal using wish tclfileName.tcl. I want to create it like .app or some other way without terminal. eg. user tap on file and it will launch like other MAC OSX application works.

Comment: Find solutions in following link http://wiki.tcl.tk/12987#pagetoc707b3879.    6. Packaging Applications 
6.1. How do I turn my script into a double-clickable app?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [Platypus](https://www.sveinbjorn.org/platypus), an open source tool which lets you create Mac .app bundles from command line scripts, including Tcl scripts.